# How to restore locally a database from its big dump file

Tags: mysql, restore, dump

OS X 10.6.8
 MAMP 3.0.5
The dump file weighs 600 MB, so I don't use phpmyadmin, but command line instead.

original DB : smoothit
empty DB in which restore the original DB : smoothitbis
original DB dump file : smoothit-16-05-2014.sql

I tried under OS X shell:

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p smoothitbis < /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/recuperationsmoothit/smoothit-16-05-2014.sql
```

under mysql shell

```
mysql -uroot -proot smoothitbis < /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/recuperationsmoothit/smoothit-16-05-2014.sql
```

without creating an empty database

```
mysql -uroot -proot < /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/recuperationsmoothit/smoothit-16-05-2014.sql
```

Each time, the answer is similar for example to the impput of a new table in an existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

First check that Is your dump file contains create database syntax and use database query or not ?
And then take action accordingly that whether to add database name or it will create own..

Comment: How to check that my dump file contains create database syntax ?

Comment: I know that the dump file is a text document but none or my word processing appiications opens it. Anyway I have tried both cases, with and without create database request

Comment: Whats the exact problem?
is the database partially loaded , giving some error?
or blank uploaded or else?

Comment: The opeeratin is canceled because thefile is too big

Comment: then you can check max_allowed_packet in configuration file...
Is this error in error log ?

Comment: No, only delay is mentioned. I have set different values in php.ini : post_max_size=1024M upload_max_filesize=1024M max_execution_time=86000 max_input_time=86000 memory_limit=2048M mysql.connect_timeout=86000

Comment: I found why "Each time, the answer is similar for example to the impput of a new table in an existing DB" : I forget the ";" delimiter a the end of my requests. I have thus made a new try with this delimitr added, but then I have a syntax error, that is the exact problem, not a delay problem that I encountered while using mhmmyadmin